# MaterialCardView causes InflateException

Tags: android, inflate-exception

Whenever i am running my app,my app got crashed with this following exception shown in Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flickr/com.example.flickr.PhotoDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class androidx.cardview.widget.MaterialCardView
```

This XML file(PhotoDetailActivity) is causing this inflate exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp">
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my Build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flickr"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

I have no idea why it is happening?

Can anyone help me in resolving this error?

Comment: Are you sure your app theme is using the material theme as parent ?

Comment: @PraveenSP Sorry,i did not get it.I am new in android development.

Comment: try adding `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"` to it

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes,now it is working well.Can you tell me why we have to add this line?

Comment: Because your previous one was having `AppCompat` theme and you want to use `MaterialTheme`

Comment: it seems to be a requirement  of the library. either you supply it as them to the view or use as app them (https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)